# Python reads empty bytearray from character device

Tags: python, file, chardev

I got a character device for some gpio on an industrial PC running under Debian.

Reading in C works pretty fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd;
    fd = open("/dev/bsw_gpio", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("could not open device");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned char val;
    int ret;
    ret = read(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
    if (ret == 0)
        printf("Value : %d\n", val);
    else
        printf("No val read\n");

    if(close(fd) != 0) {
        printf("Could not close file");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Edit

I forgot; this gets me the status of the two io pins as value between 0 and 3 and works well.. But I need to do this in Python.

Whereas Python reacts this way

```
>>> import os
>>> fp = os.open("/dev/bsw_gpio", os.O_RDWR)
>>> os.read(fp, 1)
b''
```

or, using normal open:

```
>>> with open('/dev/bsw_gpio', 'r+b', buffering=0) as fp:
...     fp.read()
... 
b''
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain what result you are expecting instead?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3929826)

Comment: Have you tried running your script with sudo?

Comment: @KlausD. i expect a byte value between 0 and 3 - sorry, forgot to mention this.
- KlausD. I know it won't help to get my answer faster.. but it made me feel better
- SlLoWre same result with sudo.

Comment: You might want to include that in the question.

Comment: i did.. thanks for the hint

Comment: That C code looks broken. Remember that `read()` returns the number of bytes read, zero on end-of-file, negative on error.

Comment: well yes but that doesn't matter to this example.
i've found out that i need to read into a bytearray variable of the exact size

Answer (score 0):

i found out that I need to read into a fixed size bytearray. Since I needed to convert to int after, I just used an array of 2 bytes, reversed it and have the correct value now.

```
class DigitalIO():
   
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        öffne die Datei
        '''
            
        self.file = open(DigitalIO.FILENAME, 'r+b', 0)
    
    def read_value(self):
        '''
        lies einen Wert
        '''
        val = bytearray(2)
        self.file.readinto(val)
        val.reverse()
        return int(val.hex(), 16)

    def write_value(self, value):
        '''
        schreibe einen Wert
        '''
        self.file.write(value.to_bytes(1, 'little'))
```